# How to replace contents of p tag to div tag?

Tags: html

I need to replace the content of my P tag to DIV tag in almost 600 html pages.Each page had different name and topic.

```
<div id = "topicname"></div>
<P><A NAME="4u_uvt"></A><B>FiBu-Übergabe</B></P>
```

I wrote this Javascript and called in my HTML function, but it is not working

```
<script>
  var mydivpchange=document.querySelectorAll("p");
  document.getElementByID("topicname").innerHTML=mydivpchange[1].innerHTML;
</script>
```

Comment: can't you just apply some css rules, which make a `p` element behave like a `div`?

Comment: Well, you only have one `p` tag, and you're trying to get the second element...

Comment: I have lot of p tags in each HTML. so just find and replace will not work. But this is the first p tag in the body

Comment: Are your html files stored locally or remotely?

Comment: It is stored locally only

Comment: You want it to be replaced permanently ? Because you should simply edit the html files and not using javascript.

Comment: Are all 600 pages in a single file?

Comment: What is your desired output from your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// get tag names that are <p> only in first occurence
let test=document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

    // create a div element
    let y=document.createElement('div');

    // state that p = div
    y.innerHTML=test.innerHTML;

    // replace test with y
    test.parentNode.replaceChild(y, test);
```

```css
div{ background:red;}
```

```html
<p>test</p>
 <br/>
<p>test2</p>
 <br/>
<p>test3</p>
```

Comment: I need to change only the first p tag, not all

Comment: Edited. The script above will change only the very first p tag of your html codes.